# Quadratic field such that a certain finite set of primes split

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Given a finite set $S$ of primes, is it possible to find an imaginary quadratic field $K$ such that all primes in $S$ are split completely in $K$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Let me just assume WLOG that $S$ contains $2$. Let $D$ be squarefree. If $D \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ has ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 - x - \frac{D-1}{4})$. Then $2$ splits if and only if $D \equiv 1 \bmod 8$. An odd prime $p$ splits if $D \equiv 1 \bmod p$, so it suffices to find a (negative) squarefree $D \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ such that $D \equiv 1 \bmod p$ for all odd primes $p \in S$. In fact a prime with this property exists by Dirichlet's theorem.

Comment: 2 splits completely in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ for $d$ squarefree and 1 mod 8, right?

Comment: Oops. Let me fix that.

Comment: I think with that addition the answer to OP's question is yes and you can do it explicitly with CRT + quadratic reciprocity, I am a little lazy on working out the details and would make a mistake anyway!

Comment: Also, you want $D \equiv 1 mod 4$.

Comment: @countinghaus: I am not sure things are so easy. I think I know how to prove that there are infinitely many primes $D$ congruent to $1 \bmod 4$ such that $\left( \frac{D}{p} \right) = 1$ if $p$ is _prime_, but here we need $p$ to be a product of primes and the Jacobi symbol no longer reflects quadratic residue-ness.